# Gravity Forms: tracking form

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I’m new on this forum and I have a question about Gravity Forms.
Actually, I am using entries like orders for my customers with a field where i digit the Order Number and another field where insert the order status (completed, paid...).
I was thinking to build a “tracking form” in the frontend where customers can digit their Order Number and then they can see the status of the order.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my rough idea.
You might need to save the order status as Custom field value or Custom Taxonomy term. As you know, GF supports Hook and actions; gform_after_submittion might help in this case. In the action, you can read the tracking number, then run the query, then return the value to the form.

Comment: Thank for you reply. Can you write an example of this code?